# The GAC, gacutil.exe and Assembly Cache Viewer

Tags: .net, gac

I'm new to .NET and I have few simple questions regarding the GAC.

First of all, as far as I understand the GAC in .NET 3.5 is different from the GAC in .net 4.0 .

I also know that there are two main tools for managing the GAC : gacutil and Assembly Cache Viewer which is integrated in Windows Explorer. So my questions are the following :

- Why is Assembly Cache Viewer obsolete in .NET 4.0 ?
- I have installed .NET 4.0 and I have to GACs. How to tell gacutil.exe to target only one of the GACs ?
- I guess there are many duplicate assemblies in the two GACs am I right ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have one GAC for the .Net 2.0 runtime and a separate GAC for the .Net 4.0 runtime.

Similarly, there are two versions of gacutil.exe, one for each runtime.
Each one will only affect its GAC.

Ordinarily, there are no duplicate assemblies; the .Net 2.0 GAC contains .Net 2.0 assemblies and the .Net 4.0 GAC contains .Net 4.0 assemblies.
However, it is possible to add the smae .Net 2.0 assembly to both GACs.  (by running both gacutils)

Comment: Hm... I've thought before that gacutil from 4.0 is able to work with both GACs. Thanks for info, +1

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Still I don't understand why the Assembly Cache Viewer is obsolete in 4.0. Also how can I see exactly which version of gacutils I am using ?

Comment: @datafen: Microsoft never bothered rewriting it.  The version of gacutil depends on what folder it's coming from.  Also, when you run gacutil, it will print its version to the console.

Comment: how can one find the gacutil.exe corresponding to an old version of the runtime? my gacutil is only listing the .Net4.0 assemblies

Comment: @knocte: Install the SDK for that version.

Comment: @SLaks: I already have it (if I didn't, I wouldn't be able to compile targetting that Fx in VS, right?)

Comment: @knocte: No; VS and the SDK do not need each-other.  (AFAIK)